# Mongo DB Path setting with homebrew

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I am new to mongodb, I am install Mongodb with homebrew on OS Mac and it has been successfully installed,

Now I am writing,

```
mongod --dbpath mypath
```

What I want to achieve is, not to write every time dbpath --dbpath /path but just mongod

Any extra configuration I need to do for mac system ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you installed `mongodb` via brew, the last info displayed should have been instructions on location of the config file and starting brew as a service. If you missed that, try `brew info mongodb` :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just fork it into the background:

```
$ mongod --dbpath=yourPath --syslog --fork
```

Mongod will bo runing in the background. To stop it use `kill`

```
$ pkill mongod
```

This is the prefered way, so you don't have to start a new terminal session.

But if you do not care about that you can just make an alias:

```
 $ alias mongod='mongod --dbpath yourPath'
```

To make it permanent you have to add it to you shell config file. I'll presume you are runing `bash` and you config file is `.bashrc`, but any other shell or config file would be similar

```
$ echo "alias mongod='mongod --dbpath yourPath'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc # reloads the shell
```